# RVM plugin not available in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Am using Jenkins 2.303.1 - Community version. We have to deploy Ruby on rails application through Freestyle/Pipeline job hence we need to install RVM plugin but it is not visible/available for us to download.

May i know the reason/any other way to install RVM plugin. Please suggest